# Having several object's property pointing to the same object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, pointers

I am working on a calendar application in .NET (C#).

In general, the user checks names from a check box list and then he can see on a calendar and all the events for each of those people.

I have for example the CalendarWeek object, CalendarEvent object, and CalendarTableCell object.

I need all of them to have a List as a property, but it must be the same list in all of them.

I guess I should use pointers for this, I didn't really understand the guide which I found so I'd like some help.

Comment: Add a list property to each class, create a List instance and assign the List to the list property of each object you have (CalendarWeek etc.). They will then point at the same list object.

Comment: are you familiar with the `ref` key word...?

Comment: are you familar with singletons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need all of them to have a List as a property, but it must be the same list in all of them.

If you need multiple objects to use the same list, there is absolutely no problem: make a list object, and pass it to the constructors of the classes that need to use it. Like all classes in C# (as opposed to `struct`s and primitives) `List<T>` and other collections are by-reference objects. What this means in your situation is that if you assign a `List<T>` to instance fields in different objects, these fields would be referencing the same list.

```
class CalendarEvent {
    public List<Stuff> ListOfStuff {get;private set;}
    public CalendarEvent(List<Stuff> myList) {
        ListOfStuff = myList;
    }
}
class CalendarWeek {
    public List<Stuff> ListOfStuff {get;private set;}
    public CalendarWeek(List<Stuff> myList) {
        ListOfStuff = myList;
    }
}
...
// Create a list
List<Stuff> theList = new List<Stuff>();
// Add things to it
theList.Add(...);
// Make CalendarEvent and CalendarWeek
var ce = new CalendarEvent(theList);
var cw = new CalendarWeek(theList);
// At this point ce.ListOfStuff and cw.ListOfStuff have the same list
```